# How to get a track name from a radio stream? javascript

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a Discord radio bot (in JavaScript) that broadcasts online radio. I want to add the command "NowPlaying", but I do not know how to get the name of the track from the online radio, does anyone know how to do this, I searched everything I could, but found nothing?

Comment: please show some code or what you have tried

Comment: Bharath, there is nothing that I can show, I found nothing all the time I searched.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the stream details every time you run the command / it triggers. Then show the saved details in np cmd.

Answer (score 0):

If that radio station's website regularly updates their current track name, then inspect the 'Network' tab on that page.
See if you find API URL where the info is coming from.

And after that you can do a JSON or XML request to that URL, then parse track name from response.

[Online radio track info example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6U6yB.png)